# Load thousands of JSON files into BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have around 10,000 JSON files, and I want to load them into BigQuery. As BQ only accept ndJSON, I spent hours searching for a solution, but I can't find a easy and clean way to convert all the files to ndJSON.

I tested `cat test.json | jq -c '.[]' > testNDJSON.json` and it works well to convert a file, but how to convert all the files at once?

Right now, my ~10k files are on a GCP bucket, and weight ~5go.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no magic here. You will need to read the objects, convert and write back. For performance, use a Compute Engine instance. Next, review the pricing and quotas on importing data into BigQuery before selecting a method to import data.

Comment: Can you share a sample your file format (with dummy values)? There is line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

Did you come across [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) in your search? Dataprep can read data from Cloud Storage, help you format the data and insert data to BigQuery for you.

Alternatively, you can use Cloud DataFlow I/O transform to deal with this automatically. See the link below for [reference](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to use a [Google-provided Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) template to transfer your files to BQ, you can use the one called [Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates)
, it's important to consider the UDF function to transform your JSON files.